# Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html - wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm trying to add a single post stylesheet to my site. I've added this to my head:

```
<?php if (is_single()) { ?><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/blog/wp-content/themes/responsive-brix/single.css" />
```

and updated my root .htaccess with:

```
AddType text/css .css
```

I keep getting the error "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html". Any ideas?

Comment: Since you are generating the stylesheet via PHP, I believe the PHP is the one sending it with the wrong type. There are a ton of options for getting your CSS into wordpress. They are outlined here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/loading-css-into-wordpress-the-right-way--cms-20402